# Trouble with easyzoom jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am working on an image gallery with a zoom feature, but when I change images the zoom is not picking up the change.  This is the first time I have ever used a jquery plugin so I am probably just needing a nudge in the right direction.

The problem is when I try to us the .swap() I am getting

TypeError: $easyzoom.swap is not a function

The API ref has this
.swap(standardSrc, zoomSrc)
Easily switch the standard and zoom image sources.

I am using EasyZoom http://i-like-robots.github.io/EasyZoom/

Code is pretty simple, zoom works on initial image, but when image swaps, zoom is still using original image.  .swap() should take care of it, but for some (likely very simple) reason I can't get it to work.

HTML:

```
    <div id="mview">
    <div class="easyzoom easyzoom--overlay">
        <a href="/media/test/IMG_20130403_084209_183.jpg" id="zoomsrc">
           <img src="/media/test/sm_IMG_20130403_084209_183.jpg" width="349" id="zoomview" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <!------>
    <div id="imgbar">
    <img src="/media/test/tn_IMG_20130403_084209_183.jpg" width="60" />
    <img src="/media/test/tn_IMG_20130403_091502_782.jpg" width="60" />
    <img src="/media/test/tn_IMG_20130403_091511_640.jpg" width="60" /></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       var $easyzoom = $('.easyzoom').easyZoom();
       $("#imgbar img").click(function(e) {
            var bigImg=this.src.replace("tn_","sm_");
            var bigImgSrc=this.src.replace("tn_","");
            $("#zoomview").attr("src",bigImg);
            $("#zoomsrc").attr("href",bigImgSrc);
            console.log($easyzoom.data('easyzoom'));
            // $('.easyzoom').swap(bigImg,bigImgSrc); //tried this too
            $easyzoom.swap(bigImg,bigImgSrc);
       });
    });
```

Thanks for your time looking at this

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not accessing the EasyZoom API. Each instance is saved via jQuery's internal storage to the target element and can be accessed like so: `$easyzoomElement.data("easyZoom")`

I've updated your example code (http://jsfiddle.net/spidre409/6Z89g/) here: http://jsfiddle.net/6Z89g/2/